# MyIsam table level locking / deadlock

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock, myisam

I having different list of tables apart of that one table is type of InnoDb and others are MyIsm type.

My problem is, I am not getting any response on my website. When I check process list on MySql I found that :

[image]

A table having list of all question that sending data , some other process in waiting to update question's column and some other process in waiting to insert data in same table.

This table contains list of question. The type is MyIsam . The size of table is about 5 GB.

How can I resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of solutions for this, some may apply, some not.

1. Add indexes to some columns
2. Change database type to innoDB
3. Take a look at your query and improve the performance

When you add indexes to you table the lookup will be much faster and therefor the table lock won't be as long.

When you change your database type to `InnoDB` the lock will only affect the row(s) the query is using, so other rows are still available for other query's

In your query itself most of the times a lot of performance can be gained by removing unnecessary `joins` or `order by` clauses. Maybe you can use temporary tables instead of multiple `subselects`, etc...